# -4 rep for deleting answers, but sometimes not - why?

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-answers

I always delete my own answers when a better answer is upvoted and accepted. There is no reason for having bad or not-satisfying answers being around.

I did not always have that behaviour. So I have a lot of none-upvoted none-accepted answers on my list. Once in a while I go back and delete some of my own none-accepted answers with no upvotes when I see there is another (better, I presume) answer accepted.

Recently I have noticed, that I get a -4 rep "fine" per answer deleted for doing this. But I do not get that "fine" when I am deleting a fresh or relatively new answer.

Why this difference? I am cool with being fined for deleting content, but why the fine for old answers, and not for new ones?

---

**Update**. I tried to make a proof of concept, by deleting **1** old answer to a question where there were another accepted answer. I ensured that my answer not had any upvotes or downvotes. So far, after +30 minutes, I have not received this self imagined "fine" of 4 rep. I think @animuson was absolutely right.

What have happend is most likely a freaky chain of coincidences. I have 3 times in a row, over a period of propably some weeks or a month, deleted two answers almost at the same time, both with apparently 0 upvotes. But one of the answers have all three times received both an upvote *and* a downvote, giving a total rep of 8, hidden behind the "0". All three times I have not been aware of those hidden rep, and then I have seen the overall rep drop 8, for two deleted answers, I began to see a pattern, and suspected there perhaps was introduced a fine for deleting old answers.

I actually really believed that this was the case!

Comment: I don't see any evidence of that -4 in your rep history, whether that means anything or not. When's the last time this happened? Are you sure it wasn't a post with an upvote and a few downvotes, and you just didn't look at the score breakdown and assumed it was all down? Just a guess.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen, no - it is obviously not visible as negative points, you are just cutted -4 off for each post you delete. Have seen this multiple times now, therefore I ask. It is also not because there is some hidden reps in upvoting/downvoting for the answers. It seems to be a rule. Delete an old answer, and you get a 4 rep "fine".

Comment: Does this negative reputation show in your profile? Can you share a link to an answer where this happened?

Comment: @Andy, cannot go back to the deleted answers. Tried, but the tab I used today for this is closed. But it has happened multiple times, so I am sure there is a pattern or a rule for this. You could try it out yourself - you have this one -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/10723528/1407478 with no votes and where there is another accepted answer.

Comment: We discourage deleting old answers - there is no reason not to leave them, and they may help someone in the future.

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate since I know the system well. I really believed there was a new feature introduced, not described in the older answers or blog posts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're seeing is the votes being reversed for deleting the post. It's not a "fine" for deletion, just the system removing the effects of the post. The reputation you gain from votes is only kept permanently if the post is both older than 60 days and has a score of at least 3.

Your most recent one in your reputation history is a -8, which is because the post you deleted had one upvote and one downvote. That originally netted you 8 reputation, which is now being reversed due to the deletion.

Comment: No, as I try to describe, it has happended multiple times, and it is -4 for reps each and every time, and the answers is always answers with no upvotes or downvotes.

Comment: @davidkonrad I know *exactly* what is going on. You are not losing 4 reputation for deleting answers. That never happens and never has. You're losing the reputation you gained. Period. Nothing else to discuss.

Comment: It may have happened multiple times, but it is all for the same reason - as animuson has just tried to explain to you.